# Gears of war 2 split screen on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, gears-of-war-2

I have one account on Xbox One, and I figured out how to play Co-op on Gears of war ultimate edition, locally, with my dad. Now I'm trying to play Gears of war 2 and onward, locally as well, with an offline guest account. Is it possible or will I be playing by myself locally?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make a second account?

Answer (score 0):

As this page states, you should be able to play local co-op on GoW 2

https://www.co-optimus.com/game/372/xbox-360/gears-of-war-2.html